# How to configure/style HTML5 Sortable grid so it matches the demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a sortable grid that mimics the functionality at http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/ where the element grabbed disappears when you click on it and it has those dotted lines remaining behind. However, copying the computed CSS on the demo page is not giving me the desired effect.

Is there some options I'm missing when initializing the sortable or something?

I'm just initializing the standard way:

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boeu4zdg/1/

Comment: Could you upvote the answer please? Trying to earn reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As author says on the [description page](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/):

> Use .sortable-dragging and **.sortable-placeholder** selectors to change the styles of a dragging item and its placeholder respectively.

To make it exactly like in demo, you need the following styles (took from demo page, removed not needed styles):

```
.sortable {
    width: 310px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.sortable.grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sortable li {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #F6F6F6;
    color: #1C94C4;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.sortable.grid li {
    line-height: 80px;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
li.sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    background: none;
}
```

See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boeu4zdg/3/).